# How to save Numpy array as tif file with projection

Tags: python, numpy, geolocation, tiff, projection

I have imported a `.tif` file into python from a LiDAR surface

```
Existing_Surface = 'Path_To_Tiff/Existing_Surface.tif'
```

I checked the projection using gdal

```
Original_Surface = gdal.Open(Existing_Surface)
projection_Original = Original_Surface.GetProjection()
geotransform_Original = Original_Surface.GetGeoTransform()
```

The imported surface has the correct projection and geotransform.

I then trimmed the tif around a shape file and converted the new image to an array using numpy.

```
Existing_example_array = [[ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
                          [ 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], 
                          [ 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], 
                          [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], 
                          [ 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], 
                          [ 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I manipulated the data within the array and am now attempting to export the numpy array.

```
data_folder = Path("Path_to_Tiff/Surface.tif")
tifffile.imsave( data_folder, Existing_example_array)
```

tifffile correctly exports the array, but the projection and geotransform is lost.
I believe that by converting the original `.tif` to a numpy array I lost my projection and geotransform. Is there a method of returning a projection and geotransform to an array and then export it back to a tiff file?

Answer (score -1):

I would not use numpy for that matter, and I will recommend another library for images processing [SimpleITK](https://simpleitk.readthedocs.io/en/master/gettingStarted.html)

And you should be able to read your file then save it again (just like this snippet)

```
import SimpleITK as sitk
sitk.WriteImage(img_out, 'img.tif',  useCompression=True)
```